# Where is def/2 defined?

Tags: elixir

Where is def/2 defined? I'm looking for authoritative documentation, i.e. something like

https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.12/Macro.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`def` is defined in the `Kernel` module [here](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.13.4/lib/elixir/lib/kernel.ex#L4760-L4762) (found the link on [this page](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.13.4/Kernel.html#def/2)).

Internally it calls `define/4`, a private function in `Kernel` defined [further down in the file](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.13.4/lib/elixir/lib/kernel.ex#L4838-L4870).

Comment: did they rewrite the core macros, because I know for sure in old versions it was part of the elixir bootstrap?

Answer (score 1):

The `def/2` macro is part of the bootstrap for the elixir compiler, it is written in erlang.

You can find it in the [`elixir_bootstrap`](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/79cd891eb86ecb7654a7acdb63769cfdd950a5c0/lib/elixir/src/elixir_bootstrap.erl#L13) module:

```elixir
'MACRO-def'(Caller, Call) -> 'MACRO-def'(Caller, Call, nil).
'MACRO-def'(Caller, Call, Expr) -> define(Caller, def, Call, Expr).
```